# Populate a variable using jQuery based on selections in a drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to build a nested array in jQuery based on a user's selection from a drop down menu.  This will be used in a JSON request at a later date.

So far my code does produce (almost) the required result, however no matter order i select the options from my drop down menu, the output (which i log in the console at the end) is always the same.

```
  $('#comboGenre').change(function () {
     var values = $('#comboGenre').val();
     var parsedJSON = JSON.parse($data); //Data returned from ajax request
     for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i += 1) {
         $genreList = parsedJSON.genre[i];
         console.log($genreList);
     }
 });
```

So if i select RPG and Action from my drop down, the output gives me RPG and Driving.  If i selected RPG, Driving and Action (in that order), i get what i would expect RPG, Driving and Action.

So it's just iterating through my JSON, when really it should be returning the 'selected' option.

How can i achieve this?

My JSON looks like this if it's useful:

```
 {"genres": [{
        "genre": "RPG",
        "publishers": [{
            "publisher": "Square",
            "games": [{
                "game": "FFX",
                "rating": [
                    12, 15
                ]
            }]
        }]
    }, 
            {
        "genre": "Driving",
        "publishers": [{
            "publisher": "Turn10",
            "games": [{
                "game": "Forza",
                "rating": [
                    5
                ]
            }]
        }]        
    },
    {
        "genre": "Action",
        "publishers": [{
            "publisher": "EA",
            "games": [{
                "game": "COD",
                "rating": [
                    18, 20
                ]
            }]
        }]        
    }        
]}
```

EDIT:

I've also tried this:

```
 $('#comboGenre').change(function () {
     var parsedJSON  = JSON.parse($data);
     $genreList = "";
     $.each(parsedJSON.genres, function(index, value){
     $genreList = parsedJSON.genres[index];
     console.log($genreList);
     });
 });
```

And i end up getting ALL the objects in my JSON, so from here, i'm only wanting to add the selected object to the `$genreList` variable.

Comment: Is that a multi select box? and "driving" and "action" are 2 different options?

Comment: It is yes, bootstrap UI

Comment: And it'd be very useful to help you if you created a fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Does this look right? -> http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/CJPV5/1/

Comment: Hi, thanks for that, doesn't quite work.  My current code takes the genre (and all it's children) and adds it to a variable (which i use later).  I've tried this code and while it does get the selected genre - it doesn't bring back all the children of it.  Just the name 'RPG' etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you broke out some of the logic and created a genre finding function and used the selected string to find the proper object you could then put the object into the variable you will use later. I do some checking to ensure that the genre that has been selected isn't already in my array which is because I am using the multiple select

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vkTFq/

Code:

```
$(function(){
var selectedGenres = []; 
var genres =[{"genre":"RPG","publishers":[{"publisher":"Square","games":[{"game":"FFX","rating":[12,15]}]}]},{"genre":"Driving","publishers":[{"publisher":"Turn10","games":[{"game":"Forza","rating":[5]}]}]},{"genre":"Action","publishers":[{"publisher":"EA","games":[{"game":"COD","rating":[18,20]}]}]}]
    $('#comboGenre').change(function() {

        $(this).find(":selected").each(function() {
            var selectedGenre = findGenre($(this).val())

            if (!genreAlreadySelected(selectedGenre.genre)) {
                selectedGenres.push(selectedGenre);
            };


        });
        console.log (JSON.stringify(selectedGenres));
    });

    function genreAlreadySelected(genre){
        for(var i = 0; i < selectedGenres.length; i++){
            if (genre == selectedGenres[i].genre) {
                return true;
            };
            return false;
        }
    }

    function findGenre(genre){
        for(var i = 0; i < genres.length; i ++){
            console.log(genre)
            if(genre == genres[i].genre){
                return genres[i];
            }
        }

    };


});
```